# MongoDB Count Perfomance very slow

Tags: performance, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

We are on Mongodb version : 2.4.9

Looks like there was a fix on 2.3.2 for Count problem

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1752

But still my count operation is very slow I cannot able to do pagination just because of the count operation taking like 10 seconds for 3.5 million records.

Any one have idea on this?

**Edit**

Explain() results in:

```
{

    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor by_dateCreated",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 143736,
    "nscannedObjects" : 2893069,
    "nscanned" : 2893069,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2904859,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 2904859,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 135,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 117730,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "DateCreated" : [[ISODate("2014-06-24T13:36:26.952Z"), ISODate("2013-08-28T13:36:26.952Z")]]
    },
}
```

**Edit2**

Query (I am using C# Driver provided by MongoDB)

```
var entities2 = (from e in this.collection.AsQueryable<SocialRecord>()
                 where (e.DateCreated >= fr) && (e.DateCreated <= to) 
                 && bArray.Contains(e.TermMonitorIds) 
                 &&(sources.Contains(e.SocialType))
                 select e).OrderByDescending(e => e.DateCreated);
return entities2.Count();
```

**Edit3**

Document Structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53a456b27f781d19f40ac76c"),
    "DateCreated" : ISODate("2014-06-20T15:35:56.000Z"),
    "SocialType" : "facebook",
    "RecordId" : "1474971936_10202431655820767",
    "UserId" : "1474971936",
    "UserProfileUrl" : "",
    "UserProfilePictureUrl" : "/Downloads/v3/432bfeb8-901e-45a4-b739-1f3f48b69d61/facebook/2014-6/1946689/10492432_10202426005479512_740185019259071925_t.jpg",
    "Description" : "",
    "MediaHiResUrl" : "",
    "MediaLowResUrl" : "",
    "MediaMedResUrl" : "",
    "SocialCount" : NumberLong(354),
    "SocialCountType" : "likes",
    "Sentiment" : "",
    "SentimentScore" : "0.0000000",
    "IsLocalContent" : true,
    "IsExactMatch" : true,
    "IsHashTag" : false,
    "IsActive" : false,
    "MediaType" : "image",
    "TermMonitorIds" : [ 
        "432bfeb8-901e-45a4-b739-1f3f48b69d61"
    ],
    "UserName" : "",
    "DisplayName" : "",
    "DirectUrl" : "",
    "IsUk" : true,
    "IsEnglish" : true,
    "Language" : "en",
    "Location" : "GB",
    "DataVersion" : "v3"
}
```

When i try to create a compound index on by_dateCreated_termMointerIds_socialType like below

```
{
    "DateCreated" : -1,
    "SocialType" : 1,
    "TermMonitorIds" : 1
}
```

Its slowing up the Count query even further down.

Datecreated is the field that narrow down the search so much. So i left it with one index on Datecreated.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you are counting? All documents in the collection or is there a Query?

Comment: As @PeteGarafano says, a query and example and an explain will go a long way. But counts in MongoDB can be a little slow since the btree does not keep count of its parts as such it has to count them

Comment: i am trying to do pagination, i got an IQueryable which skips and takes data but i need to know the count of records to know how many page numbers to display in view.

Comment: @DheerajPalagiri then you need to show us the LINQ statement or call .Explain on the query. Something like this `new MongoClient().GetServer().GetDatabase("MyDb").GetCollection("MyCol").Find(new QueryDocument()).Explain()` if using LINQ, you can call .Explain on the returned cursor.

Comment: As far as I know counting of records is very much dependent on your cpu clock.

Comment: Even though you have only added the explain and not the query I cna already see that the query is hitting all documents, even outside of the index. This means that your doing an in memory count of the physical docs which will be dirt slow. Can you show the query?

Comment: @sammaye what do you mean by in memory count, you mean .Count() is there a better way to get count. Documentation shows .Count() is the way to get count.http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/#csharp-driver-linq-tutorial

Comment: Well first off all try making it so that your index covers the criteria for your query at least, that way you can count from the index, see what it is like after that, it should only need to count 140K odd.

Comment: Can you comment out OrderByDescending and calculate the time spent again?

Comment: More importantly can you give an example of the underlying document your only index or chosen index contains the "DateCreated" only. You need some other fields in a compound index, but it looks as though at least one of those is an array.

Comment: @Sammaye Actually if i try to create compound index its taking more time than index on Datecreated, its wierd may be its because of the dynamic query.the compound index size 0.3GB where as dateCreated index is 0.1GB. is it something to do with the upgrade to 2.6? as MongoDB is talking about index intersection?

Comment: @Neil yes TermMonitorIds field is an array.

Comment: @IsmetAlkan My index on Datecreated is Descending so orderbyDescending doesn't make any difference i think... but i will try thanks...

Comment: Is that the only field that is an array? Have you tried creating another index?

Comment: Yes that is the only field, i updated my question with document structure. When ever i create an compound index it still slows the things down :(

Comment: What is your index definition that you have tried? The reason your question is dragging on unanswered and with "so many" comments is you are not providing enough information for people to see the problem. Better to add all of that to your question and then just tag the person who is asking in a comment to let them know you have added it. People should read your question to solve the problem, not the comments.

Comment: And for the real kicker. Look at your data with some form of distinct query or count. Which of your criteria would possibly reduce the possible matches down by the most. Do dates vary the least? Is it the "TeamMonitorIds"? Or is it the social type? What you want to do is "narrow down" the results by the least possible matches for the particular criteria. The smallest one you commonly use comes first. That is query optimization in a nutshell.

Comment: This is the second question today where I have seen that loading an index is apparently slower than loading physical documents from the disk on 2.6. Can you show the explain for the compound index? I cannot explain how it would longer to count to 150,000 odd documents for a query that hits the index completely than 2.89m documents who have to loaded from disk

Comment: Mind you that being said the default count is actually on the _id index so I am wrong there, but still to fill the query criteria it would load from disk

Answer (score 0):

I used to mongo driver for .net core and my counter method;

```
var result = collection.CountDocuments(_ => true);
```

usage link:https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/